# How to get a hotkey to fire more than one line when using ShiftAltTab?

Tags: autohotkey

On my system I have a long script that makes use of a library, [MouseGestureL](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=31859), as well as standard AHK Hotkeys. I am stuck on an issue, I have asked the developer but sadly I have not gotton a reply, he is always happy to help, so this is very rare from him.

For clarities sake, I will describe the libraries code in standard AHK code.

Lets say line `30` of my script is:

```
Rshift::
MsgBox, Activate or start up Web browser
...
```

and then further down down the script, perhaps at line `900`, there are two lines of code, consisting of standard AHK hotkeys:

```
...
>+Backspace::AltTab
>+Enter::ShiftAltTab
```

The problem I am having is that the library I am using (Line `30`) is not aware of me pressing `RShift`+`Backspace`, so If I `AltTab` back to another window, it will activate my browser anyways. I can simply fix this with standard AHK `If`/`Else` or a function the library provides for such a situation but the special AHK `AltTab` facilities is tying my hands behind my back.

I am in essence looking to do something like this:

```
...
Rshift::
If (Rshift_Abort)
    Rshift_Abort := 0
Else 
    MsgBox, Activate or start up Web browser
...
...
>+Backspace::AltTab
    ;MG_Abort()  The function the library provides to get it to "Stand down one time"
    Rshift_Abort := 1
    Return
>+Enter::ShiftAltTab
    ;MG_Abort()
    Rshift_Abort := 1
    Return
...
```

If the above is simply not possible due to the nature of `AltTab`/`ShiftAltTab`.

Is it possible to create my own version of `AltTab` using `Keywait`/`GetKeySate`.

I ask because, I have barked up this very tree some time ago. Trying to emulate AHKs `AltTab` by holding down `Rshift` and using `Backspace`/`Enter` to cycle back and forth, I simply could not recreate the `AltTab` feature.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works here in a script with no other code and no other script running

```
Rshift:: WinActivate, ahk_exe msedge.exe

>+Backspace::AltTab
>+Enter::ShiftAltTab
```

MS Edge gets active only by releasing Rshift and only after RShift is pressed alone (not after AltTabbig).

Try adding the rest of the code after those lines progressively and see how it works.

See also [Debugging a Script](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/Scripts.htm#debug).

Comment: Right, I know the feature you mention is built into standard AHK. This would work fine an envoiroment where I am only using standard AHK code but as I explained in my OP, I am using a library that is not aware of me pressing `Shift`+`Enter`.

Comment: I too use MouseGestureL in my main script  and a lot of other libraries as well. And the whole works fine if I add the above code to my hotkeys. I personally have a single "master" script that is always running on my system. It can run other temporary scripts. If you're using more than one script the most recently started script will intercept the keyboard hook preventing it to be used in the other scripts (except it's running in a lower priority or the previous script is running in admin mode).

Comment: Hey your clarifications are what did it. Thanks allot for that.